# How to Implement Multi-dimensional Time-Series Data Queries in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I'm trying to work with time-series data using CnosDB, but I've run into a challenge: I need to perform multi-dimensional queries, but I'm not sure how to achieve this in CnosDB.

I'd like to be able to filter and aggregate data based on timestamps and other attributes (such as device ID, sensor type, etc.). I know in traditional SQL databases, this can be achieved using multiple WHERE conditions, but it doesn't seem to work the same way in CnosDB.

I've looked through the official documentation, but couldn't find detailed information on multi-dimensional queries. Could someone provide some sample code or guidance to help me implement multi-dimensional time-series data queries in CnosDB?

Answer (score 0):

CnosDB's ordinary table supports multiple FIELDs. The documentation is as follows.
https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/v2.3/reference/sql.html#table